# ViewPager не отображает объекты при перелистывании(ImageView)

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Всем привет. Возникла проблема, ViewPager не отображает картинки при перелистывании. При появлении активити с viewpager, у него отображается первая картинка + 1 лежит в контейнере (следующая, тобишь вторая). Когда я перелистываю, то отображается вторая и 3-я вроде как подгружается. Но при перелистывании на 3-ю отображается серый экран. Всего картинок 6. При прописывании параметра `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);` все картинки отображаются корректно.

Код адаптера:

```
public class SwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
private int[] imageCount = {R.drawable.pres0,R.drawable.pres1,R.drawable.pres2,R.drawable.pres3,R.drawable.pres4,R.drawable.pres5};
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public SwipeAdapter(Context context) {
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return imageCount.length;
}


@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout, null);
    ImageViewTopCrop imageView = (ImageViewTopCrop) item_view.findViewById(R.id.image);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageCount[position]);
    container.addView(item_view);
    return item_view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((View)object);
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    return arg0 == arg1;
}}
```

swipe_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.companyname.projectname.ImageViewTopCrop
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/image"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

И похоже вся проблема упирается в кастомный ImageViewTopCrop

ImageViewTopCrop.java

```
public class ImageViewTopCrop extends ImageView {
public ImageViewTopCrop(Context context)
{
    super(context);
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
}

public ImageViewTopCrop(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
}

public ImageViewTopCrop(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
}

@Override
protected boolean setFrame(int l, int t, int r, int b)
{
    Matrix matrix = getImageMatrix();
    float scaleFactor = getWidth()/(float)getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
    matrix.setScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, 0, 0);
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    return super.setFrame(l, t, r, b);
}
```

}

Без использования кастомного ImageView всё работает, с ним - нет. Но без него у меня не скэйлиться изображение так как мне нужно, так что убрать его я тоже не могу. Есть какие-нибудь идейки?

Comment: А вы не пробовали проверить, хорошо ли отображаются все ваши 6 ImageViewTopCrop  без ViewPager? Может, дело не во ViewPager, а в них?

Comment: При установке параметра `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);` все 6 ImageViewTopCrop отображались корректно, в данный момент отображаются лишь первые два. Думаю, без ViewPager ImageViewTopCrop также будет отображаться корректно, но на всякий случай сейчас проверю.

Comment: ImageViewTopCrop без ViewPager работает отлично

Comment: Думаю, вам поможет отображение страниц через фрагменты вместо View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл решение данной проблемы. Я переписал класс ImageViewTopCrop и всё заработало:

```
public class ImageViewTopCrop extends ImageView{

public ImageViewTopCrop(Context context)
{
    super(context);
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
}

public ImageViewTopCrop(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
}

public ImageViewTopCrop(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    recomputeImgMatrix();
}

@Override
protected boolean setFrame(int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    recomputeImgMatrix();
    return super.setFrame(l, t, r, b);
}

private void recomputeImgMatrix() {
    final Matrix matrix = getImageMatrix();

    float scale;
    final int viewWidth = getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
    final int viewHeight = getHeight() - getPaddingTop() - getPaddingBottom();
    final int drawableWidth = getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
    final int drawableHeight = getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();

    if (drawableWidth * viewHeight > drawableHeight * viewWidth) {
        scale = (float) viewHeight / (float) drawableHeight;
    } else {
        scale = (float) viewWidth / (float) drawableWidth;
    }

    matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
}}
```